# error: inconsistent types 'std::optional<double>' and 'std::nullopt_t' deduced for lambda return type

Tags: c++

```
auto operator  | (auto f1, auto f2) {
    return [f1, f2]() {
        if(f1) {
            return f2(f1.value());
        }
         return std::nullopt;
    };
}


int main() {
    std::optional<int> a{11},b{};

    auto z = a | [](auto b) -> std::optional<double>{
        return b / 3.0;
    };

    auto x = z();
}
```

how to make lambda return type generic in operator| function ?

idea is to implement operator | which take optional and lambda , lambda is processed only if optional is not nullopt and return optional of return type of lambda

Answer (score 6):

You can use `?`:

```
auto operator  | (auto f1, auto f2) {
  return [f1, f2]() {
    return f1?f2(f1.value()):std::nullopt;
  };
}
```

as its rules for combining types is less strict than auto return type deduction.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the trailing return type:

```
auto operator  | (auto f1, auto f2) {
    return [f1, f2]() -> decltype(f2(f1.value())) {
        if(f1) {
            return f2(f1.value());
        }
         return std::nullopt;
    };
}
```